# The number of ways to form $1110€$ using $45$ notes of $20€$ and $18$ notes of $50€$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let 45 notes of 20€ and 18 notes of 50€, how many different forms we can have 1110€?

I don't know write the congruence, I had thought the following:

$$45 x \equiv 1110 \pmod{20}$$

$$18 x \equiv 1110 \pmod{50}$$

Comment: Use `\pmod{20}` for $x\equiv y\pmod{20}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can take a zero off (dividing by the GCD of $10$), having $45$ notes of $2$ and $18$ notes of $5$ to make $111$.  Now you need an odd number of $5$ notes.  What odd numbers leave you within the range that you can make up with the number of $2$ notes you have?

Comment: But the congruence that I have writen is ok?

Comment: No, you are not required to use all of either kind of note, so the answer cannot have $45$ as other than some limit of a range.  If you have $x$ notes of $20$ and $y$ notes of $50$ you are trying to solve $20x+50y=1110$ with $x,y$ integers in the allowable range.

Comment: Ok, so the range is: $0 \leq x \leq 45$ and $0 \leq y \leq 18$

Comment: Right.  Now can you find the solution with the minimum $y$?  Then note that you can trade off five $20'$s for two $50'$s and have the same amount of money.  How many times can you make that trade?  Another approach would be to find the maximum $y$ and see how many numbers are in the range.  You should get the same answer either way.

Comment: Ok, the solution is 7?

Comment: Yes, that is what I get.  You can have any odd number from $5$ through $17$ of the $50$ notes.